# React Router 6 action not subscribing to isSubmitting from React Hook Form + not working with RTK Query Mutation either

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom, react-hook-form

Simplified React component with form:

```
const itemSchema = z.object({
  title: z.string().max(50),
});

type ItemFormFields = z.infer<typeof itemSchema>;
const {
  register,
  handleSubmit,
  reset,
  setError,
  formState: { isSubmitting, errors }
} = useForm<ItemFormFields>({
  defaultValues: {
    title: "title placehnolder"
  },
  resolver: zodResolver(itemSchema)
});

// RTK's isLoading and error remain not updated for mutation hooks
// but the same work as expected with query hooks done through .initialize() in RRv6 loader
// const [_createItem, { isLoading, error }] = useCreateItemMutation();

const submit = useSubmit();
const actionData = useActionData<typeof itemsAction>();

const hasError = actionData && 'error' in actionData && isString(actionData.error);

useEffect(() => {
  if (hasError) {
    const { error } = actionData;
    setError('root', {
      message: error
    });
  }
}, [actionData, hasError, setError]);

return (
  <div className="new-item">
    <Form
      onSubmit={(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        handleSubmit((data: ItemFormFields) => {
          submit(data, { method: 'post' });
          reset();
        })(event);
      }}
    >
      <div className="new-item__form-body">
        <div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="title">Title:</label>
          </div>
          {errors.title && <div>{errors.title.message}</div>}
        </div>

        <div>
          <div>
            <input
              id="title"
              type="text"
              required
              {...register('title')}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="new-item__form-footer">
        <Button
          disabled={isSubmitting}
          type="submit"
        >
          {isSubmitting ? 'Loading...' : 'Submit'}
        </Button>
      </div>

      {errors.root && <div>{errors.root.message}</div>}
    </Form>
  </div>
);
```

React Router Action function:

```js
import { ActionFunction, ActionFunctionArgs, redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
// ...
const fromEntries = <T extends object>(data: FormData) => Object.fromEntries<string | number | File>(data) as T;
    
export const itemsAction = (async ({ request }: ActionFunctionArgs) => {
  const data: FormData = await request.formData();
  const formData: ItemFormFields = fromEntries(data);
  const mutation = store.dispatch(api.endpoints.createItem.initiate(formData));

  try {
    const { id } = await mutation.unwrap();
    return redirect(`/items/${id}`);
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      error: 'Post-Validation error message placeholder' 
    };
  }
}) satisfies ActionFunction;
```

Everything works as except for React Hook `isSubmitting` which remains unsubscribed and false/undefined. Same with `isLoading, error` from const `[_createItem, { isLoading, error }] = useCreateItemMutation();` if I try with RTK instead.

The useForm data successfully gets submitted through `handleSubmit` and RRv6 `submit` - the action successfully fetches the `formData` with the correct Zod schema type `ItemFormFields`. The RTK mutation initiate successfully POSTs a new entity to the database which then returns the id in the response and the RRv6 `redirect` happens where it successfully fetches through a loader and everything goes smoothly... except for the `isSubmitting` formState in `useForm` that remains unsubscribed and RTK's isLoading also remains undefined. `isSubmitting` works as expected in a regular async example, but once it goes to the `action` through the `void submit` from `useSubmit` from React Router 6 - it never subscribes and never updates to `true`. I would assume it needs a `Promise` but RRv6's `useSubmit` provides with a regular void and does the whole flow behind the scene.

EDIT: Just regular React Router 6 (browser data router) with a route for /new:

```
{
  path: 'new',
  element: <NewItem />,
  action: itemsAction
}
```

Comment: Am I just missing or not seeing it, where is `isSubmitting` declared?

Comment: True! I simplified too much I guess, haha. I re-added isSubmitting to formState. I was playing around isLoading through RTK before I posted the question, so I've forgotten to re-add isSubmitting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `useForm`'s `formState.isSubmitting` value is only true *while* the submit handler function is executing, and since it's a synchronous function and only executes two lines it's only submitting for a very short duration. Since the route action is what is doing the work you'll need to queue off the action processing to render any loading UI. You can access this via the [`useNavigation`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigation) hook from React-Router-DOM.

See [navigation.state](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigation#navigationstate):

> - **idle** - There is no navigation pending.
> - **submitting** - A route action is being called due to a form submission using `POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH`, or `DELETE`
> - **loading** - The loaders for the next routes are being called to render the next page
>
> Form submissions with `POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH`, or `DELETE` transition
> through these states:
>
> ```
> idle → submitting → loading → idle
> ```

You can check that the action is currently not idle:

```
const navigation = useNavigation();
const isSubmitting = navigation.state !== "idle";

...

<Button disabled={isSubmitting} type="submit">
  {isSubmitting ? "Loading..." : "Submit"}
</Button>
```

Example:

```
import {
  useActionData,
  useSubmit,
  useNavigation,
} from "react-router-dom";

...

const {
  register,
  handleSubmit,
  reset,
  setError,
  formState: { errors }
} = useForm<ItemFormFields>({
  defaultValues: {
    title: "title placehnolder"
  }
  resolver: zodResolver(itemSchema)
});

const submit = useSubmit();
const actionData = useActionData<typeof itemsAction>();
const navigation = useNavigation();

const isSubmitting = navigation.state !== "idle";

...

return (
  <div className="new-item">
    <Form
      onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => {
        submit(data, { method: "post" });
        reset();
      })}
    >
      <div className="new-item__form-body">
        <div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="title">Title:</label>
          </div>
          {errors.title && <div>{errors.title.message}</div>}
        </div>

        <div>
          <div>
            <input id="title" type="text" required {...register("title")} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="new-item__form-footer">
        <Button disabled={isSubmitting} type="submit">
          {navigation.state !== "idle" ? "Loading..." : "Submit"}
        </Button>
      </div>

      {errors.root && <div>{errors.root.message}</div>}
    </Form>
  </div>
);
```